# Can't use raw after truncate rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

The trouble is if I use `<% @description = (truncate(post.content, :separator => '[---MORE---]', :length => 0))%>` and then I try to print it - `<%= raw @description %>` I still see all html tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`truncate` escapes the string by default, but you can turn it off using `:escape` option:

```
@description = (truncate(post.content, :separator => '[---MORE---]', :length => 0, :escape => false))
```

Other approach would be to mark the `post.content` as html safe:

```
truncate(post.content.html_safe, ...
```

If you do this you can even remove the `raw`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!